# pygame.error: Unable to open a console terminal

Tags: python-3

In a .py file this line states "screen = pygame.display.set_mode ( (1, 1) )".  It yields an error "error code in python--pygame.error: Unable to open a console terminal".  Can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: Are you using Raspberry Pi OS with Desktop? Some complete runnable code would help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to run a graphical program over ssh or with putty?

If so you either need to use vnc or run directly on the Pi within the Desktop.

Comment: Thanks CoderMike.  Running from ssh..  Have not tried vnc or running on the Pi Desktop.  Will try both methods.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying in invoke a pygame window remotely over ssh, then make sure you specify the 'display' environment variable inside your code like this:

```
os.environ["DISPLAY"] = ":0"
pygame.display.init()
```

Note 'display' is not always ':0.0' but most of the time it is. You can find it by opening a local terminal window and typing 'echo $DISPLAY'

Comment: `echo $DISPLAY` returns nothing for me

Comment: Using a pi that tried to write in the framebuffer "/dev/fb0" this does not work and $DISPLAY displays nothing

Comment: works on rPi 4 running Buster. What are you running?